# Install Gnome3 (gnome-shell) on Kubuntu problem

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gnome

I tried to install gnome shell on Kubuntu with this commands

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
 sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

and I just found gnome classic session when logging in, Are there any messing things??‬

Comment: same here :( ... any one has solution??

Comment: It gives me a segmentation fault!!

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-Shell and Unity requires a more stricter conformation to newer graphical standards than Kubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu.

First I would confirm that you have the ability to run Unity - Gnome-shell has similar requirements to Unity. See the linked question below.

If you have "no" as any answers or a "segmentation fault" - then you need to have a much closer look to what graphics card you have and what drivers you are using.

For example:

- If you are using ATI graphics then check you are using ATI proprietary graphics.  If your card is to old for these drivers, you probably will not be able to run Gnome-Shell/Unity 3D.
- If you are using NVIDIA you have two choices - use the proprietary drivers or the experimental 3d open-source drivers.
- If using Intel - ensure they are fairly modern (last 5 years).
- If using Intel/Nvidia hybrid graphics then ensure that you have looked into Ironhide/Bumblebee as per the linked question
- Any other graphics card - most probably you will not be able to...

Attempting to use Gnome-Shell without the graphics driver prerequisites - gnome-shell will not be displayed and you will "fallback" to gnome-classic.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I tell if Ubuntu supports hardware-accelerated graphics on my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop/65268#65268)
2. [How to switch between hybrid Graphics Intel/nVidia?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59489/hybrid-graphics-intel-nvidia)

Comment: i have  'segmentation fault' in test of potential compatibility, my laptop is Dell inspiron N5110 with hybrid graphic adapter (" Intel (R) HD Graphics Family " and "nvidia GeForce GT525 ") when i try to install Recommended driver from additional drivers  the GUI was crashed  so that i back to Nouveau driver (default one in Kubuntu) so what can i have to do now? by the way unity or KDE session is works great but the problem in Gnome session, i have classic one instead of gnome3

Comment: you'll need to look into the hybrid graphics question linked above.