# Ubuntu 12.04 and 3D

Tags: 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell if Ubuntu supports hardware-accelerated graphics on my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop)

In My sony Vaio, the graphic card is 'Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series]'. I am not able to use the 3d effects in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop) should tell you whether your graphics card is capable of running unity in 3D

Comment: i am getting the results as 'no for 2 values 1. Unity 3D supported. 2.Not software rendered. is solution to activate 3D in My machine?

Comment: In that case either it is a bug in the driver or the chipset is just not capable of running 3d.  I don't know which.  One option is just to stick with 2D which I presume is working ok for you.