# How can I enable Unity 3D on an FX5200 graphics card?

Tags: 12.04, 3d, myunity

How can I change from Unity 2D to 3D on ubuntu 12.04?

I am running an AMD NX2100 with 512k memory and NVIDIA FX5200

I've tried numerous cures/downloads/fixes noted within Ask Ubuntu, but when ever I run MyUnity I will always get this same message:

```
Your Ubuntu 12.04 is running in 2D mode. Many features will not be available.
```

Most everything within the MyUnity menu is grayed out.

I am new to Ubuntu and have been working on this for more than two weeks to no avail.

Comment: perhaps the output of the unity-support-test (http://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop) would help here together with the nvidia driver you may nor may not be using from the Additional Drivers window - please add any replies to your Question.  Thanks.

Comment: Old question, I know..but...I have the very same card and I think the actual culprit must be a severe bug in the `nouveau` driver, because Firefox has the 5200 blacklisted as well for (almost) any kind of H/W acceleration. And that is for a reason, because once I try to enable it by force, I get "graphics confetti", which is so extreme that I have to hand-edit `prefs.js` to be able to work with Firefox the usual way again.

Comment: This unanswered question about Ubuntu 12.04 (EOL now) is 5+ years old and OP hasn't signed on since the day it was posted. There was never a response to the suggested fix in comments. VTC as `not reproducible`.