# How to run unity-3D on Desktop

Tags: 12.04, unity

My output of `lspci | grep VGA` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
```

Can I enable unity-3D on my PC? If so, tell me how I can please.

Thank you

Comment: Are you running Unity 2D now?

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` still work? Also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop