# Will my Laptop run Raring Ringtail without problems?

Tags: drivers

Intel i5 core processor (2.6gHz)
4gb of ddr3 ram
500gb hard drive
Integrated graphics (Intel HD graphics 4000)

Comment: Best way is to run Ubuntu Live Cd on your mobo before install. Usually this will give you a taste of Ubuntu on real machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements),

Ubuntu Desktop Edition

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

Download the Ubuntu Live CD and try it out.

While on running the live system, check how your unity support is,

[How do I tell if Ubuntu supports hardware-accelerated graphics on my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop)

In a terminal, run:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

This will tell you how well supported your hardware is (or rather your graphics card) out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Many have installed in systems with those specs. But different vendors have different UEFI or BIOS implementations that sometimes make a difference.

Intel only has one open source driver for its video chip. But sometimes boot parameters are required for the newest.

Linux 3.2 To 3.8 Kernels With Intel Ivy Bridge Graphics
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_linux32_38&num=1
Intel HD4000
http://communities.intel.com/thread/34221
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2089640
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2126191