# Firefox is lagging after update to the 29 version

Tags: 12.04, updates, firefox

Today's update of Firefox to the 29 version makes browsing very slow.

For example Firefox incredibly lagging when I am zooming or moving on google maps.

Does anyone the same problem? How can I speed it up?

My OS: Ubuntu 12.04, x64

Comment: Do you have any plugins/addons installed and if yes, which ones?

Comment: Have the same problem (Ubuntu 12.04.4). Reset didn't help. Have all the things turned to "yes" though in unity_support_test -p...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to reset Firefox to factory defaults, this is actually something Firefox proposes to do if it detects that the start-up takes too long. Beware, however, this procedure **will delete all your installed add-ons and your search engine settings**.

To do a factory reset, follow the [instruction on this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).

Another thing you could check is whether hardware graphics acceleration is set up correctly. The answer [to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop) describes how to do that.

Comment: I propose to first test this by first disabling all addons before reseting it via the 'help'->'Restart with addons disabled' to check if there will be any difference.